# Printing Duration in Java so that it is Sortable Lexicographically

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a list of [Joda Duration](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) objects. I want to convert them to a list of strings so that the strings are legible to humans and the list is sortable lexicographically. The range of data is anywhere from 5 minutes to a week. I have thought of the following options:

1. Milliseconds. This is not sortable and so doesn't work (11 comes before 3 lexicographically) and also not readable.
2. [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (25 hours and 2 minutes would be 0000-00-01T01:02). This is sortable but very hard to read.
3. ISO 8601 duration (same example as above would be P1DT1H2M). This is neither readable nor sortable.
4. Something like DD:HH:mm (e.g. 01:01:02). This is a bit hard to read but it is sortable at least.

Is there a standard textual representation of durations for this purpose that won't surprise users? If so is there a standard function that knows how to generate this textual representation?

Comment: 05 days and 12 hours and 01 minutes, --> sortable and readable?

Comment: Or maybe 05d 12h 01m it's a bit shorter and almost as readable. My problem is that all these things feel like I am reinventing the wheel when there should be a standard way of doing things.

Comment: when it comes to time, not very experienced in jodatime, but we normally just sort our dates in miliseconds (unix time) then print on any format we want it

Comment: The problem is that I display this data to the user in a table that is sortable lexicographically and I don't want to implement different sorting schemes for different columns in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the fact that you have ranges from minutes to weeks, I suggest you to apply the **alternative duration format of ISO-8601**. This standard was explicitly developed to supply lexicographically sorted representations. Joda-Time has [some support](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISOPeriodFormat.html#alternateExtendedWithWeeks()) here:

```
Duration d = new Duration(100000000L); // in milliseconds
Period p = d.toPeriodFrom(new DateTime(), PeriodType.yearWeekDayTime());
PeriodFormatter f = ISOPeriodFormat.alternateExtendedWithWeeks();
String s = f.print(p);
System.out.println(s); 
// P0000-W00-01T03:46:40 (one day, 3 hours, 46 minutes and 40 secs)
```

Maybe the year portion will still disturb you but that is just the ISO-representation and will always have the value 0000 with your duration values.

**Update and minor correction:**

Just to clarify, strictly speaking, the form "Pyyyy-Www-ddThh:mm:ss" is not really ISO. If you read the original ISO-8601-paper (section 4.4.3.3) then only four alternative forms are mentioned for the calendrical part:

- PYYYY-MM-DD
- PYYYYMMDD
- PYYYY-DDD (extended ordinal form)
- PYYYYDDD (basic ordinal form)

So what Joda-Time offers here is rather an invention not based on ISO-standard but might be convenient for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks. It's still not very user friendly but I guess it is good enough.

Comment: @BenjyKessler Keep in mind that any lexicographically sorted representations require fixed formats and not flexible length as typical for many human readable formats. So the alternative ISO-form is a compromise between readability and sorting requirements.